# Subscript out of range error, for loop memory match game

Tags: java

I am getting a subscript out of range error to complete my memory match game program in java. It is a 6 by 6 board that has random numbers in the coordinates. What number should I use in the first for loop (cnt1 <= ?)

```
public static int[][] shuffleHard() 
{
    int startHard[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18};
    int cardsHard[][] = new int[100][100];
    Random ran = new Random();
    int hold, num =0 ;
    for (int cnt1 = 0; cnt1 <= ?; cnt1++) 
    {
        for (int cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < 36; cnt2++) //randomize the cards
        {
            cnt1 = ran.nextInt(10000) % 15;
            hold = startHard[cnt2];
            startHard[cnt2] = startHard[cnt1];
            startHard[cnt1] = hold;
        }
    }

    for (int cnt1 = 0; cnt1 < 6; cnt1++) // put values in places
    {
        for (int cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < 6; cnt2++)
        {
            cardsHard[cnt1][cnt2] = startHard[num];
            num = num + 1;
        }
    }
    return cardsHard;
```

Comment: Don't use `cnt1` to hold a random variable if you are using it for the loop

Comment: Unrelated, but is your thought that doing a random number < 10000 % 15 will be "more random"? Also, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List).

Comment: You use cn1 in startHard[cnt1] so in your first loop you should use cnt1 < startHard.length